# Index stops working after upgrade

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  component_tbl.meta,
  component_tbl.enabled,
  component_tbl.id,
  component_tbl.name,
  component_tbl.parent,
  component_tbl.option,
  component_tbl.ordering,
  component_tbl.iscore
FROM
  components AS `component_tbl`
LEFT JOIN
  nodes AS `assignment` ON assignment.component = component_tbl.option AND assignment.type LIKE 'ComComponentsDomainEntityAssignment,com:components.domain.entity.assignment'
WHERE
  (
    component_tbl.parent = 0 AND component_tbl.enabled = 1 AND component_tbl.id NOT IN(
    SELECT
      assignment.id
    FROM
      nodes AS `assignment`
    WHERE
      (
        assignment.type LIKE 'ComComponentsDomainEntityAssignment,com:components.domain.entity.assignment'
      ) AND(
        assignment.name = 'com:people.domain.entity.person' AND assignment.access = 2
      )
  ) AND(
    (
      assignment.name = 'com:people.domain.entity.person' AND access = 1
    ) OR assignment.owner_id = NULL OR component_tbl.option = "com_stories"
  )
)
```

and it works great on my current server with MySQL 5.5.52, but I'm currently upgrading to a new server with MySQL 5.7.20 and it's much much slower. On 5.5.52, it's about .3 seconds and on 5.7.20 it's ~4 seconds. So I did an EXPLAIN on both servers:

MySQL 5.5.52:

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | type            | possible_keys                                                                                    | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                        |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | component_tbl | ALL             | parent_option                                                                                    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   27 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | assignment    | range           | type,component,type_enabled,type_modifed_on,type_created_on,type_status_update_time,type_default | type    | 767     | NULL |  697 | Using where; Distinct        |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | assignment    | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,type,type_enabled,type_modifed_on,type_created_on,type_status_update_time,type_default   | PRIMARY | 8       | func |    1 | Using where                  |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
```

MySQL 5.7.20

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | partitions | type            | possible_keys                                                                                     | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                                                        |
+----+--------------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | component_tbl | NULL       | ALL             | parent_option                                                                                     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |    25 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | assignment    | NULL       | ALL             | type,component,type_enabled,type_modifed_on,type_created_on,type_status_update_time,type_default  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 98853 |   100.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0xF8060); Distinct |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | assignment    | NULL       | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,id,type,type_enabled,type_modifed_on,type_created_on,type_status_update_time,type_default | PRIMARY | 8       | func |     1 |     5.00 | Using where                                                  |
+----+--------------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you compare the two, you'll see that in the second query, the assignment select, it uses the `type` index in one, but not the other. The `INDEXES` for both tables are much the same.

MySQL 5.5.52

```
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name          | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| nodes     |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | id                   | A         |       74387 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          0 | person_username         |            1 | person_username      | A         |       18596 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          0 | person_userid           |            1 | person_userid        | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          0 | person_useremail        |            1 | person_useremail     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | last_comment_by         |            1 | last_comment_by      | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | created_by              |            1 | created_by           | A         |        3915 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | modified_by             |            1 | modified_by          | A         |        2755 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | person_lastvisitdate    |            1 | person_lastvisitdate | A         |       12397 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type                    |            1 | type                 | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | component               |            1 | component            | A         |          34 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | owner_id                |            1 | owner_id             | A         |        2010 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | parent_id               |            1 | parent_id            | A         |       18596 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | story_target_id         |            1 | story_target_id      | A         |         312 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | story_object_id         |            1 | story_object_id      | A         |       74387 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | story_subject_id        |            1 | story_subject_id     | A         |        1352 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | story_comment_id        |            1 | story_comment_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | start_date              |            1 | start_date           | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | end_date                |            1 | end_date             | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_enabled            |            1 | type                 | A         |         422 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_enabled            |            2 | enabled              | A         |         630 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_modifed_on         |            1 | type                 | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_modifed_on         |            2 | modified_on          | A         |       74387 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_created_on         |            1 | type                 | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_created_on         |            2 | created_on           | A         |       74387 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_status_update_time |            1 | type                 | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_status_update_time |            2 | status_update_time   | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_default            |            1 | type                 | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_default            |            2 | is_default           | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

MySQL 5.7.20

```
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| nodes     |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | id                 | A         |       98853 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          0 | id                      |            1 | id                 | A         |       98853 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | last_comment_by         |            1 | last_comment_by    | A         |         735 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | created_by              |            1 | created_by         | A         |        2157 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | modified_by             |            1 | modified_by        | A         |        2182 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type                    |            1 | type               | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | component               |            1 | component          | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | owner_id                |            1 | owner_id           | A         |        1346 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | parent_id               |            1 | parent_id          | A         |        8868 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | story_target_id         |            1 | story_target_id    | A         |         999 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | story_object_id         |            1 | story_object_id    | A         |       11165 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | story_subject_id        |            1 | story_subject_id   | A         |         743 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | story_comment_id        |            1 | story_comment_id   | A         |        2329 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | start_date              |            1 | start_date         | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | end_date                |            1 | end_date           | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_enabled            |            1 | type               | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_enabled            |            2 | enabled            | A         |          28 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_modifed_on         |            1 | type               | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_modifed_on         |            2 | modified_on        | A         |       98853 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_created_on         |            1 | type               | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_created_on         |            2 | created_on         | A         |       98853 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_status_update_time |            1 | type               | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_status_update_time |            2 | status_update_time | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_default            |            1 | type               | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| nodes     |          1 | type_default            |            2 | is_default         | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Some changes were made to the table during the migration, but nothing too dramatic. Is there a change in MySQL that would cause this change in function? Is there a better way to optimize this query?

I'm at a loss as why the index would seemingly stop working and I'd appreciate any input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the indexes:

- Single-column indexes with cardinality=2 are unlikely to ever be used; drop them.
- An index that is the left part of another index -- drop the shorter.  (eg: `INDEX(type)` vs `INDEX(type, enabled)`).
- 4 `UNIQUE` keys?  That is very unusual, and *probably* "wrong".

This is flat out *wrong*:  `assignment.owner_id = NULL` -- It is always FALSE, since `NULL` is never equal to anything, even `NULL`.  You need `assignment.owner_id IS NULL`.

Instead of `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`, do either `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * ... )` OR `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL`.

Although it is OK to say `type LIKE 'ComComponentsDomainEntityAssignment,com:components.domain.entity.assignment'`, it would be better to say `type = 'ComComponentsDomainEntityAssignment,com:components.domain.entity.assignment'`

`nodes AS assignment` -- It is a bit confusing to use the same alias for two different instances.

Some of the parentheses are redundant.

Please fix some things before I try to continue with the Question.

Comment: I tested out your suggestions and your idea to use = instead of `LIKE` on the join solved my problem. It's using the type `INDEX` again. Although, now it's ref. Any idea why this stopped working in the newer version of MySQL? Were there any changes or settings that might've caused this?

Comment: The query is generated by a database abstraction and I don't have full control over changing some parts of it. I'll try to implement your suggestions. It's part of a repository design pattern and some columns aren't used as frequently now as they will be. Only the primary key is left.

Comment: 5.5 to 5.7 has some big changes in default charset (did any columns change?) and Optimizer techniques.  _Most_ Optimizer changes are improvements; you may have hit a hiccup.  "Abstraction" -- condolences; this forum is littered with apps that have outgrown 3rd party software.